# core 2 web and api development oauth2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

Now i am working on developing api based application . Web , android and IOS my own apps call this api for getting data . My question is identity server4 needed for this application cause my users login using their user name and password . And not any third party application is not connected with me . 
But i want token based authentication with refresh token . I need a guideline which  authentication system I use for my application

Comment: IdentityServer = Oauth2 + oidc. If you don't need SSO then you don't need IdentityServer. You are welcome to use it, but it's overkill.